# Breaking out of Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive for asking this question. I have gone through quite a bit of solutions and yet it does not work for me.

I have about 5 input fields and if it finds an illegal character on any of the input fields (if someone enters one and tries to save), it should alert a message.

So far, when it finds one, it does alert but then it goes and saves it.

I am trying to break out of the each() loop, return false does not work.

A better solution would also be appreciated.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/T2vT9/2/)

```
// Illegal Character Check
$('.illegal-check').click(function () {
    var illegal = /[&<>]/;
    $( ".scoring input:text" ).each(function() {
        var inptStr =$(this).val();
        if (illegal.test(inptStr)===true) {
            alert('Your Scoring field(s) contain these & < > invalid characters. Please remove them and try again.');
            return false;
        }
    });//each
});//click
```

Comment: `$('#answer16').click` instead of `$('.illegal-check').click`

Comment: If this is meant as a form, you should wrap `<form>` around it and apply a handler on submit.

Comment: It is working fine. I have added a console log here - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/T2vT9/4/ and the each loop stops after the first invalid record.

Comment: @musefan indeed. my bad

Comment: I've tried that Fiddle, and it works for me. There are 4 $( ".scoring input:text" ) items, but the `each` loop only iterates twice for me.

Comment: I get alert in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.illegal-check').click(function (e) {
    ...
    if (illegal.test(inptStr)===true) {
        ...
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The reason why your data is still getting saved is that even though you're breaking from the *loop* by using "return false;" your data submission is still in progress. You need to cancel it as well. For that, you use the event argument "e", passed to the event handler, by calling its "preventDefault" function.

Comment: It would be nice if you expanded on your answer and explained how this will solve the problem. Providing a code dump doesn't really help the OP to understand what the problem is

Comment: @musefan added a comment; it's one-liner and the code is self-explanatory but anyway; muse are awesome, btw :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a variable to see whether an illegal value has been found [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/T2vT9/5/):

```
// Illegal Character Check
$('.illegal-check').click(function () {
  var illegal = /[&<>]/;
  var found = false;
  $( ".scoring input:text" ).each(function() {
    var inptStr =$(this).val();
    if (illegal.test(inptStr)===true) {
        alert('Your Scoring field(s) contain these & < > invalid characters. Please remove them and try again.');
        found = true;
    }
  });
  if(!found){
    alert("Nothing has been found")
  }else{
    alert("Illegal char has been found");
  }
});
```

Comment: -1: You have removed the only thing that will break the loop (you know, what the question is asking). Suggestions, without solutions, do not qualify as answers

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add a submit handler on the form instead of a click event on a table cell.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // ...
    if (illegal.test(inptStr)===true) {
        alert('...');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    // ...
```

Here, the event gets passed to the function and any error would prevent this event from triggering the actual submission.

Comment: The reason I am not using on the form is that there are some more forms and it gets created automatically and I don' t have access to the code side. I return false or e.preventDefault(); does not work even though it is meant to...;o(

Comment: @19eggs You can use `$('#answer16').closest('form').on('submit', ...)` then.

Comment: Again depending on a user logged..there could be some more inputs and the ids keeps on changing...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.fn.each`, similar to `$.each`, will break out of the loop with `return false` and continue to the next iteration with any non-falsy `return`. [It's documented on the API site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each#entry-longdesc).

By all rights, this part of your code should be fine.

Comment: But it's not fine, because the click handler itself should `return false;` so that the click doesn't propagate or perform a similar method on the passed event.

Comment: @Jack *this part of your code* relates to *breaking out of  each loop*. Your assertion is more to do with event resolution than jQuery loops. It's a bit of a leap to assume this is what the OP actually meant, but you may be right — maybe edit the question (title in particular) to make it clear this isn't about breaking out of loops?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated fiddle. Check for the errors in a separate function

```
$('.illegal-check').click(function () {
    if(checkIllegal()) evt.preventDefault();
});

function checkIllegal(){
   var illegal = /[&<>]/;
   var isIllegal = false;
   $( ".scoring input:text" ).each(function() {
      if (illegal.test($(this).val()) && !isIllegal) {
         alert('Your Scoring field(s) contain these & < > invalid characters. Please remove them and try again.');
         isIllegal = true;
         return false;
      }
   });
   return isIllegal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2vT9/7/

Comment: You can change the event from .illegal-check to your submit button selector. The .illegal-check container does not have any default action, so evt.preventDefault doesn't actually makes sense. Change that to your submit button and it should work

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` statement does break out of the `$(...).each(...)` loop. Your problem is that it still goes on and saves it. You should also stop the event from executing its default action using `e.preventDefault()`. *(note: this was also mentioned in a code dump by m1kael, which did not add an explanation)*

That amount to this code:

```
// Illegal Character Check
$('.illegal-check').click(function (e) {
    var illegal = /[&<>]/;
    $( ".scoring input:text" ).each(function() { // loop over elements in form
        var inptStr = $(this).val();
        if (illegal.test(inptStr)===true) {
            alert('...'); // show alert
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action on click (stop submit)
            return false; // break out of elements loop, no more alerts needed
        }
    });//each
});//click
```

Comment: I was in doubt whether I should comment on his answer, or add my own. Because there was no explanation at all with his answer, I decided to create a new one that was an actual answer. I then added the code dump, based on his answer.

Comment: So I'm getting punished for mentioning existing work?
Edit: slightly modified the mention by M1kael

Comment: You should never reference other answers, those answers could be removed and it makes yours incomplete. Good answers should stand on there own, with no dependency

Comment: @Daan Wilmer..nope, doesn't work.. I am beginning to think the problem is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @musefan And I though I was doing good following scientific guidelines and stuff... lesson learned ;)

Comment: @19eggs Does it give two alerts when there are two errors, or does give one alert and then save? AFAIK the `return false` should work...